# Complex MySQL View

Tags: mysql, view

I'm trying to wrap my head around views. I think they are what will work best for what I need. I'll create three example tables here, but it should illustrate what I'm trying to do.

First, a table that holds the list of all Discord users who've used, or been searched by, my product:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE discord_users;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| no             | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| discord_user   | varchar(19)  | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                                               |
| is_banned      | tinyint      | NO   |     | 0                 |                                               |
| is_whitelisted | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | 0                 |                                               |
| note           | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| timestamp      | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM discord_users;
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| no | discord_user       | is_banned | is_whitelisted | note          | timestamp           |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 228937760390643713 |         1 | 0              | Stev#6666     | 2023-04-14 06:14:39 |
|  2 | 253725613439975426 |         0 | 1              | Harsh#3028    | 2023-04-14 06:14:39 |
|  3 | 533022512372645916 |         0 | 1              | ItsBranK#1337 | 2023-04-14 06:14:39 |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Second, a table that holds a list of all of the Epic Games users who've used, or been searched by, my product:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE epic_games_users;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| no              | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| epic_games_user | varchar(32)  | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                                               |
| is_banned       | tinyint      | NO   |     | 0                 |                                               |
| is_whitelisted  | tinyint      | NO   |     | 0                 |                                               |
| note            | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| timestamp       | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM epic_games_users;
+----+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
| no | epic_games_user                  | is_banned | is_whitelisted | note      | timestamp           |
+----+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | d8603dd248ad45bcb47305a68841d676 |         0 |              0 | RL.Plus   | 2023-04-14 06:15:25 |
|  2 | 0274508828c347ddaff7bb9051d2303d |         0 |              1 | EquinoxRL | 2023-04-14 06:15:25 |
+----+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Last, I have a table of Discord and Epic Games users who've linked their accounts. Foreign keys are `discord_user` and `epic_games_user` to the tables above.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE links;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| no              | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| discord_user    | varchar(19)  | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                                               |
| epic_games_user | varchar(32)  | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                                               |
| note            | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL              |                                               |
| timestamp       | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM links;
+----+--------------------+----------------------------------+------+---------------------+
| no | discord_user       | epic_games_user                  | note | timestamp           |
+----+--------------------+----------------------------------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | 228937760390643713 | d8603dd248ad45bcb47305a68841d676 | NULL | 2023-04-14 06:16:07 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------------------+------+---------------------+
```

**Note**: Not every user in the `discord_users` and `epic_games_users` tables will appear in `links`.

I would like to create a view that resembles the following - the best way I know how to describe it:

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+
| discord_user       | epic_games_user                  | is_banned | is_whitelisted |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 228937760390643713 | d8603dd248ad45bcb47305a68841d676 |         1 |              0 |
| 253725613439975426 | NULL                             |         0 |              1 |
| 533022512372645916 | NULL                             |         0 |              1 |
| NULL               | 0274508828c347ddaff7bb9051d2303d |         0 |              1 |
+--------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

It should list *all* `discord_user` and `epic_games_user`, next to the linked account, if they have one. If it does not have a linked account, the other user column, be it `discord_user` or `epic_games_user`, should be `null`.

`is_banned` and `is_whitelisted` should be true *if* those columns are true in the `discord_users` *or* `epic_games_users` tables. Obviously if they do not appear in `links`, it would only be dependant on the table it exists.

I honestly have no idea where to start on this and I would appreciate any help. I believe I can easily list those who appear in `links`, and whether they are banned or whitelisted. The trickly part is including `discord_user` and `epic_games_user` that do *not* appear in `links`, *and* prevent duplicates.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: In your desired outcome what does is_banned and is_whitelisted mean? if there is a conflict between discord_users and epic_users in this regard which should take precedence - are you going pessimistic and saying if either of is_banned = 1 then outcome should be 1?

Comment: Hi there, @P.Salmon! Yes, if either `discord_user` or `epic-games_user` has `is_banned=1` then the result should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query gets all the users in `discord_users` and, if one exists, the associated user in `epic_games_users`. The second query returns the users which exist only in `epic_games_users`.

```
SELECT
    du.discord_user,
    egu.epic_games_user,
    (du.is_banned OR IFNULL(egu.is_banned, 0)) AS is_banned,
    (du.is_whitelisted OR IFNULL(egu.is_whitelisted, 0)) AS is_whitelisted
FROM discord_users du
LEFT JOIN links l ON du.discord_user = l.discord_user
LEFT JOIN epic_games_users egu ON l.epic_games_user = egu.epic_games_user
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL,
    egu.epic_games_user,
    egu.is_banned,
    egu.is_whitelisted
FROM epic_games_users egu
LEFT JOIN links l ON egu.epic_games_user = l.epic_games_user
WHERE l.epic_games_user IS NULL
```

outputs:

| discord_user | epic_games_user | is_banned | is_whitelisted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 228937760390643713 | d8603dd248ad45bcb47305a68841d676 | 1 | 0 |
| 253725613439975426 | NULL | 0 | 1 |
| 533022512372645916 | NULL | 0 | 1 |
| NULL | 0274508828c347ddaff7bb9051d2303d | 0 | 1 |

and then just precede the above query with `CREATE VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW `your_view_name` AS
...
```

Comment: You are a God-send! I’m excited to get home from work and really look at this and examine your approach and how it works. Thank you so much!